# Delete from object if Item exists and then push again

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have the array as follows, I want to first check if the record in array already exists, and then push the similar record.

```
    arr1 = [{
        'Name': 'Ken',
         'Id' : 123,
         'Units' : 100
    }, {
        'Name': 'Kris',
        'Id': '223',
        'Units' : 100 
    }, {
        'Name': 'Ben',
        'Id': '229',
        'Units' : 100
    },
     {
        'Name': 'Alex',
        'Id': '222',
        'Units' : 100
    }]
```

Now suppose I want to add a similar record

```
{
        'Name': 'Ken',
         'Id' : 123,
         'Units' : 50
}
```

Here only the value of Units have been changed and sometimes it may also remain same.

What I want is remove the initial similar record (check by Id) and push the new one.

So my final array should be like

```
arr1 = [{
        'Name': 'Ken',
         'Id' : 123,
         'Units' : 100
    }, {
        'Name': 'Kris',
        'Id': '223',
        'Units' : 100 
    }, {
        'Name': 'Ben',
        'Id': '229',
        'Units' : 100
    },
     {
        'Name': 'Alex',
        'Id': '222',
        'Units' : 100
    }]
```

Comment: What have you try so far?

Comment: the new one: `'Units' : 100` is that right?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Find object by id in array of javascript objects](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7364150/find-object-by-id-in-array-of-javascript-objects)

Comment: should be like `'Units' : 50` ?!

Comment: btw. do you want to keep the initial order of the elements?

Comment: No order is not necessary.

Answer (score 2):

```
var newRecord = {
    'Name': 'Ken',
    'Id': 123,
    'Units': 50
};

arr1 = arr.filter(function (el) {
    return el.Id != newRecord.Id;
});

arr1.push(newRecord);
```

Demo:

```js
arr1 = [{
  'Name': 'Ken',
  'Id': 123,
  'Units': 100
}, {
  'Name': 'Kris',
  'Id': '223',
  'Units': 100
}, {
  'Name': 'Ben',
  'Id': '229',
  'Units': 100
}, {
  'Name': 'Alex',
  'Id': '222',
  'Units': 100
}]

var newRecord = {
  'Name': 'Ken',
  'Id': 123,
  'Units': 50
};

arr1 = arr1.filter(function(el) {
  return el.Id != newRecord.Id;
});

arr1.push(newRecord);

alert(JSON.stringify(arr1));
```

Comment: The OP said: What I want is remove the initial similar record (check by Id) and push the new one.

Answer (score 0):

filter out the old record based on the pertinent property and add the new one.

```
similarRecord = {
  id = 123
  ...
}

_arr1 = arr1.filter(function(obj){
  return obj.id != similarRecord.id
})

_arr1.push(similarRecord)
```

Comment: it will also remove all elements from the array

Comment: sure does. in coffeescript land with auto return. thanks @CodeiSir.

Comment: This clearly tagged as javascript. And in javascript it wont work